# Hacer que el eje Y comience en 0 en los gráficos

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Con qué trabajo: C#, Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2010

He realizado un grafico con Chart un grafico de barras donde en el eje Y debe de iniciar con cero.He revisado algunos metodos pero no logro solo agregar el valor cero.
Que estoy pasando y no me doy cuenta.
Espero su ayuda.
Muchas gracias

Esto es lo que hago ahora

[image]

Esto es lo que quiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que sale ahora

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;



            ///chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "${0:0.0000}";
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM";
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 8;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 8;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineWidth = 2;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = valorFechaMax.ToOADate();
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = valorFechaMin.ToOADate();

            foreach (var item in diccFechaInicioFin)
            {

                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(item.Value.FechaInicio.ToOADate(), item.Value.FechaFin.ToOADate(), item.Key.ToString(), 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
            }
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 8;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 8;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0.00}";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineWidth = 2;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = 2;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = montoMayor;

                    
        //chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = montoMenor;
        
        
        
        //if (montoMayor != montoMenor)
        //{
        //    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = montoMenor;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        //}

        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

Comment: ese grafico esta bien.... no entiendo que queres... si vas a hacer zoom sobre el grafico, no tiene porque salir el cero...

Comment: para mi tambien esta bien pero me piden que el eje y inicie con cero

Comment: y yo veo el cero... el chiquito no es un grafico valido, no mantiene las proporciones...

Comment: Y si estableces el eje `Y` como [logarítmico](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.islogarithmic?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_Axis_IsLogarithmic)? Si tu data es siempre positiva (no es valido para cero o datos negativos). Tal vez eso te daría la visualización que buscas.

Comment: lo que pasa es que de 0 a 90 hay un espacio enorme y no se como poder quitarlo para que se vea bien

Comment: y con esta línea descomentada `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;` te pasa lo mismo?

Comment: lo agregue pero como te das cuenta en la tercera imagen aparecen valores como 20.00 40.. 60.. valores que no tengo mapeado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **eje y** se llama *eje* porque pertenece a un plano cartesiano.

En un plano cartesiano con escala *normal*, el espacio entre cada unidad es el mismo. De eso se trata, y la interpretación de lo que se visualiza de manera gráfica, parte del principio que las unidades mantienen las proporciones en cada uno de los ejes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El *chart* muestra una porción del plano, que es como decir un *recorte* o una *ventana* hacia el mismo, como la parte coloreada en la imagen de abajo. Usualmente esta ventana se puede mover por el resto del plano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que el *chart* hace por default, es que si tus valores van, digamos, de 90 000 a 100 000, es

- Ajustar la escala vertical del plano para que todo el rango de valores sea visible en la pantalla
- Mover la ventana de visualización para que se vea solo la parte relevante, es decir, la que tiene datos (esto hace que la gráfica también sea más pronunciada)

Digamos, en la gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, si quieres mostrar el valor 0 en el eje Y, lo que le estás pidiendo al *chart* es que amplíe la vista hasta incluir el origen, y el *chart* lo que va a hacer es ajustar la escala para que en el eje sea visible desde el 0 hasta el 100 000 y, por tanto, tu gráfico se va a ver en la parte superior del diagrama.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tú quieres hacer, de mostrar un *cero* imaginario allí abajito del 90 000, no *debe* hacerse, pues el gráfico pierde toda proporcionalidad, que es uno de sus valores fundamentales.

Quizás puedas aplicar un truco para lograr mostrar ese 0 artificial que quieres, pero estás produciendo un gráfico fuera del estándar que todos usamos y que, en mi opinión, es vital mantener para interpretar correctamente la información. A la luz de la información que te doy, debes preguntarte seriamente por qué quieres ver un cero allí, dónde claramente no tiene sentido.

Como alguien te dijo en comentarios, puedes definir que la escala del eje Y es logarítmica, con lo que el espacio se va a reducir, pero también va a *aplanar* aún más tu gráfica. Explicar esta escala queda fuera del alcance de esta respuesta, pero puedes investigarlo a ver si eso resuelve tu _problema.

Comment: Gracias por la información, con esto ya puedo sustentar el cambio.